# Add arcs to tree drawn with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-trees

I want to add the green arcs, labels and boxes to this tree. (The labels will be black and red, as in the not quite minimal MWE). I don't need a programmatic solution. I can finish the job if I see how to do it once for each of the three kinds of green arcs.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\anti}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{{\color{red}\overline{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\ee}[1]{%
    node[midway,left] {#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center},
   level distance=1.5cm,sibling distance=0.5cm, 
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
  \Tree [.0
    \edge \ee{1};
    [.1
      \edge \ee{1};
      [.2
        \edge \ee{1};
        [.3
          \edge \ee{1}; 4
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{5}
        ]
        \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
        [.\anti{4}
          \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
        ]
      ]
      \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
      [.\anti{3}
        \edge \ee{1};
              [.\anti{4}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
      ]
    ]
%    second half
    \edge \ee{\anti{2}};          
    [.\anti{2}
      \edge \ee{1};
      [.\anti{3}
        \edge \ee{1};
              [.\anti{4}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
      ]
      \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
            [.4
              \edge \ee{1};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
                    [.\anti{6}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{7}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 8
                    ]
              ]
    ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to do with `forest`. Is that a possibility for you?

Comment: @AlanMunn I thought that might be the case. Yes, it's possible. I  don't have many of these to draw, so I want to minimize the amount of new tools I need to learn to use. This complicated tree came up after I learned enough qtree to do the easy ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706853/add-arcs-to-tree-drawn-with-tikz-qtree/706880?noredirect=1#comment1757464_706880), and being a different topic, here's a separate answer with a different focus.

Basic ideas:

- introduce `named nodes` as [shown before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706880/245790)
- define useful `styles`, to be used with the next item
- place new `\node`s with these styles at the remembered postions (named)
- `\draw` some lines between them for the parallels

If you look carefully `tikz-qtree` seems to connect its tree nodes slightly off-center, at least sometimes. So, though the styles `sq` and `crc` define a minimum size (basically making them a square or circle) this attempt fails, resulting in a non-parallel line:

```
    \node[sq] (X0) at (A0){};   
    \node[crc] (X1) at (C1){}; 
    \draw[teal] (X0.south west) -- (X1.south east); % <<< no parallel line !
```

So the alternative I choose is:

- using polar notation instead, like `(X1.340)` (intersection with nodes shape at 340deg)
- adjusting angles "by eye"

You could also use e.g. `([yshift=-2mm] X1)`, but this probably won't result in a real advantage.

For a more uniform visual result you should perhaps also require a useful `minimum size` or `minimum width` for all nodes of the tree. If these values are large enough, all black rectangles will have the same dimensions, besides my A4 one etc.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}  % <<<
\usepackage{tikz}   % <<< see manual
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\anti}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{{\color{red}\overline{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\ee}[1]{%
    node[midway,left] {#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every tree node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center},
    level distance=1.5cm,
    sibling distance=0.5cm, 
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)},
    sq/.style ={draw=teal!100!black!80, minimum size=9mm},
    crc/.style={draw=teal!100!black!80, minimum size=8mm,circle},
  ]
  \Tree [.\node(A0){0}; % <<<
    \edge \ee{1};
    [.\node(C1){1}; % <<<
      \edge \ee{1};
      [.2
        \edge \ee{1};
        [.3
          \edge \ee{1}; 4
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{5}
        ]
        \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
        [.\node(B4){\anti{4}};  % <<<
          \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
        ]
      ]
      \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
      [.\anti{3}
        \edge \ee{1};
              [.\anti{4}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
      ]
    ]
%    second half
    \edge \ee{\anti{2}};          
    [.\anti{2}
      \edge \ee{1};
      [.\anti{3}
        \edge \ee{1};
              [.\anti{4}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
      ]
      \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
            [.\node(A4){A4};    % <<<
              \edge \ee{1};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
                    [.\anti{6}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{7}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 8
                    ]
              ]
    ]
    ]
  ]
  
    % ~~~ extra-nodes and connectors ~~~~~~
    \node[sq] (X0) at (A0){};   
    \node[crc] (X1) at (C1){}; 
    \draw[teal] (X0.south west) -- (X1.340);    
    
    
    % ~~~ some connectors ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[teal,dashed] (A0) -- (A4);
    \draw[teal,
          loosely dashed, <->] 
          (A0) to[out=-10,in=90] node[sloped,above]{off-road}(A4);
%   \draw[dotted,blue] (B4) -- node[below,pos=.7,anchor=west]{note!}(A0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted both. Will accept one or the other when I decide which to use.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it:

- see ch. 4 in the manual
- place extra `node`s
- `\draw` later
- you may need to modify your `anti`-macro

[image: result]

Besides the `controls` statement as given in the manual I tend to favor replacing `--` in a `\draw` command by `to[out=angle,in=angle]`, which I think is easier to visualize, hence to control.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   % <<< see manual
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\anti}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{{\color{red}\overline{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\ee}[1]{%
    node[midway,left] {#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,rectangle,align=center},
   level distance=1.5cm,sibling distance=0.5cm, 
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
  \Tree [.\node(A0){A0};    % <<<
    \edge \ee{1};
    [.1
      \edge \ee{1};
      [.2
        \edge \ee{1};
        [.3
          \edge \ee{1}; 4
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{5}
        ]
        \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
        [.\anti{4}
          \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
        ]
      ]
      \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
      [.\anti{3}
        \edge \ee{1};
              [.\anti{4}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
      ]
    ]
%    second half
    \edge \ee{\anti{2}};          
    [.\anti{2}
      \edge \ee{1};
      [.\anti{3}
        \edge \ee{1};
              [.\anti{4}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
      ]
      \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
            [.\node(A4){A4};    % <<<
              \edge \ee{1};
              [.5
                \edge \ee{1}; 6
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; \anti{7}
              ]
              \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
                    [.\anti{6}
                \edge \ee{1}; \anti{7}
                \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 8
                    ]
              ]
    ]
    ]
  ]
    % ~~~ some connectors ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[teal,dashed] (A0) -- (A4);
    \draw[teal,
          loosely dashed, <->] 
          (A0) to[out=-10,in=90] node[sloped,above]{off-road}(A4);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### P.S.

Though you can use your `\anti` macro inside a node, it's probably not the best way to do it:

```
...
        \edge \ee{\anti{2}};
        [.\node(B4){\anti{4}};  % <<<
          \edge \ee{1}; \anti{5}
          \edge \ee{\anti{2}}; 6
        ]
...
    \draw[dotted,blue] (B4) -- node[below,pos=.7,anchor=west]{note!}(A0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code:

- defines `\node(B4){\anti{4}};` to the lower left
- draws a blue dotted line to (A0)
- puts a node at position `pos=.7` along that path (which is just a straight line here)
- inserts a node with text there, `below`
- anchors it `west`, i.e.makes text appear like starting always from this nodes right side

[image: result2]

Comment: Looks like something I can work with. I see how to make the tag for the node different from the contents of the node. How do I change the style of the nodes connected by the new edges? In my picture it's a hand drawn extra box, but an oval or circle or (and?) color change would do. I also need a parallel new edge in some places.

Comment: Let me think about the extra shapes: there are ways to do it. // Can you pleas give one or two examples about parallel edges? You could add a sketch to your question (though it perhaps qualifies for a new one …). . thank you

Comment: The sketch in the question shows a green edge parallel to the black edge from the root 0 to node 1.